# How to derive the height of this closed vessel?

Tags: calculus, geometry

> A closed vessel tapers to a point both at its top $E$ and its bottom $F$, and is fixed with $EF$ vertical. When the depth of the liquid inside equals $x\,\mathrm{cm}$,the volume of the liquid equals $x^2(15-x)\,\mathrm{cm}^3$. Find the length $EF$.

Given the above information, how can I find the length $EF$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume is maximal when the vessel is full. Deriving:

$$\frac{dV}{dx} = \frac{d(x^2(15-x))}{dx} = -3x^2 + 30 x$$

To obtain an extremum, the derivative must equal 0:

$$-3x^2 + 30 x = 0 \iff x = 5 \pm 5$$

We obtain a minimal volume of $0\,\mathrm{cm}^3$ for $x = 0$, and a maximal volume of $500\,\mathrm{cm}^3$ for $x = 10$. As such, the height of the vessel is $10\,\mathrm{cm}.$